# Powershell determine the remote computer OS

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, windows-xp, powershell-2.0

I wrote a script to copy files to the "All Users" desktop or "Public Desktop"

However we have a mixed environment. Some people are using Windows XP and other people are using Windows 7.

```
$SOURCE = "I:\Path\To\Folder\*"
$DESTINATION7 = "c$\Users\Public\Desktop"
$DESTINATIONXP = "c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop"

$computerlist = Get-Content I:\Path\To\File\computer-list.csv

$results = @()
$filenotthere = @()
$filesremoved = @()
foreach ($computer in $computerlist) {
    if((Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
    {   
        Write-Host "\\$computer\$DESTINATION\"      
        Copy-Item $SOURCE "\\$computer\$DESTINATION\" -Recurse -force        
    } else {
        $details = @{            
            Date             = get-date              
            ComputerName     = $Computer                 
            Destination      = $Destination 
        }                           
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        $results | export-csv -Path I:\Path\To\logs\offline.txt -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }    
}
```

Comment: [How can I determine the OS of a remote computer?](http://superuser.com/q/323238/241386)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DESTINATION is empty. Expanding on Keith's suggestion:

```sh
foreach ($computer in $computerlist) {
    if((Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
    {
        $OS = Get-WmiObject -Computer $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
        if($OS.caption -like '*Windows 7*'){
            $DESTINATION = $DESTINATION7
        }
        if($OS.caption -like '*Windows XP*'){
            $DESTINATION = $DESTINATIONXP
        }
    }
}
```

This could avoid the error you're getting also. `empty $DESTINATION`.

Answer (score 3):

In your foreach loop through $computerlist you can grab the OS Caption for each computer by using [WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx):

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject -Computer $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
```

Ant then check the $OS

```
if($OS.caption -like '*Windows 7*'){
    #Code here for Windows 7
}
#....
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you catch the exceptions? Copy-Item : Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

At I:\Path\To\Code\powershell\copy.ps1:194 char:22
+             Copy-Item <<<<  $SOURCE "\\$computer\$DESTINATIONXP\" -Recurse -fo
rce
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman 
   ds.CopyItemCommand

Comment: In Powershell 2.0 you can just use [Try/Catch](https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different goal...But thanks for the basics.

```
 del C:\scripts\OS.csv
$computerlist = Get-Content c:\scripts\computerlist.csv
foreach ($computer in $computerlist) {
    if((Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
    {   
        Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer |
        select-object CSName, Caption, CSDVersion, OSType, LastBootUpTime, ProductType| export-csv -Path C:\Scripts\OS.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```